# C# .NET DirectoryEntry.MoveTo

Tags: c#, .net, directoryentry

Can you use the .NET DirectoryEntry.MoveTo to move an object to another Active Directory?

I guess it depends on how the .MoveTo method is working, does it create a separate connection and get the object locally and then make a separate connection again?

If it tries to do it in the same context then I can assume this would not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Well - why don't **you** just give it a try and see what it does!

Comment: Restrictions are outlined in detail in the MSDN documentation for the underlying AD method, [IAdsContainer::MoveHere()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Whether they apply to your case is impossible to tell from the question.  If you have no idea then just try it.

Comment: Thanks Hans, this answered my question. Post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!